# How to convert this confusing line of Python into R

Tags: python, r, pandas

I am very new to Python, and I wonder what the following line of code is doing and how could it be written in R:

```
df['sticky'] = df[['humidity', 'workingday']].apply(lambda x: (0, 1)[x['workingday'] == 1 and x['humidity'] >= 60], axis = 1)
```

For instance, what is the meaning of `lambda x: (0, 1)`?

P.S.
`df` is a `pandas` dataframe

Comment: Boy that is one piece of unreadable code.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Considering it prompted the reader of the code to post a question asking what it does, I'd say you're right :)

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes, though a little more context would be useful. Is `df` a `dict` or a numpy dataframe?

Comment: @kdopen: df is a numpy dataframe

Comment: @kdopen: sorry, it's a panda dataframe

Comment: yep, see numpy and pandas used together so routinely I forget pandas is there

Comment: Arghh - I've been trying to wrap that line so it's more readable without scrolling but can't do it. Anyone else want to try (and keep it valid)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's start from the `lambda`. The complete expression is:

```
 lambda x: (0, 1)[x['workingday'] == 1 and x['humidity'] >= 60]
```

and it's an anonymous function that takes one argument `x` and returns:

- `1` if `x['workingday'] == 1 and x['humidity'] >= 60`
- `0` otherwise

the `(0, 1)[...]` trick is used to return `0` or `1` instead of Python booleans `False` and `True`. It exploits the fact that `False` and `True` will be coerced to numerical `0` and `1` when used in place of a numeric value, e.g. as array (or tuple) index. For instance, if the expression evaluates to `True`, cell `1` of the tuple is accessed, which contains `1`.

This function is mapped on every row of the (Pandas?) dataframe (actually, only on filtered columns `'humidity'` and `'workingday'`) and the result is stored in `'sticky'` column. That said, you can translate the same expression in R using an anonymous `function` and [`apply`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/apply.html):

```
df$sticky <- apply(df[, c("workingday", "humidity")], 1, function(x) {
    x["workingday"] == 1 & x["humidity"] >= 60;
});
```

(the filtering is probably not necessary, but my R skills are quite rusty).

However, there is a more idiomatic way of achieving the same, as kdopen wrote:

```
df$sticky <- df$workingday == 1 & df$humidity >= 60
```

Comment: I'd have used `int(x['workingday'] == 1 and x['humidity'] >= 60)` to convert a boolean to an integer instead.

Comment: Now for the R equivalent :)

Comment: `axis = 1` means by row

Answer (score 2):

The idiomatic R equivalent would be

```
df$sticky <- df$workingday == 1 & df$humidity >= 60
```

Assuming the desire is to get an indicator column.

Stefano has nicely explained the Python code. A fully expanded version of the lambda might be

```
def func(x):
    if x['workingday'] == 1 and x['humidity'] >= 60:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

But you'd never write that

Answer (score 0):

I have to say this is weird way to apply a function to a pandas df, anyway this is an example which shows what it does:

```
In [280]:
# create the df
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.arange(10), 'b':[1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5,5]})
df

Out[280]:
   a  b
0  0  1
1  1  1
2  2  1
3  3  2
4  4  2
5  5  3
6  6  3
7  7  4
8  8  5
9  9  5
```

The lambda expression is calling `apply` and passing `axis=1` which means row-wise and test each named column for whether the expression is True or False, the `(0,1)` casts this to an `int`, otherwise you'd get a boolean dtype returned.

```
In [285]:

df.apply(lambda x: x['a'] > 5 and x['b'] < 5, axis=1)
Out[285]:
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
6     True
7     True
8    False
9    False
dtype: bool
```

With the `(0,1)` cast:

```
In [282]:
# apply a lambda, test if 'a' is greater and 5 and 'b' is less than 5, row-wise, cast the result to 1, 0 if True or False
df.apply(lambda x: (0,1)[x['a'] > 5 and x['b'] < 5], axis=1)
Out[282]:
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    0
4    0
5    0
6    1
7    1
8    0
9    0
dtype: int64
```

the pandas way would be to do it like this:

```
In [284]:

((df['a'] > 5) & (df['b'] < 5)).astype(int)
Out[284]:
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    0
4    0
5    0
6    1
7    1
8    0
9    0
dtype: int32
```

I don't know R so can't comment on that

Answer (score 0):

A `dplyr` complete/reproducible solution:

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(1492)
df <- data_frame(working_day=sample(0:1, 100, replace=TRUE),
                 humidity=sample(20:90, 100, replace=TRUE))

df %>% mutate(sticky=working_day==1 & humidity >=60) -> df
```

If you *really* need `0` or `1`:

```
df %>% mutate(sticky=as.numeric(working_day==1 & humidity >=60)) -> df
```